# Previously declared permissions (2 permissions) google play app release

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to create a new release with no sensitive permissions asked. but when i go to app releases it shows :`

Previously declared permissions (2 permissions)

android.permission.READ_SMS

android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS`

I deleted all artifact libraries apks drafts .
What is the procedure to get rid of it?

Comment: First unpublish the existing production apk, then upload new one. Also, make sure you are uploading this apk to production and not in the BETA.

Comment: Check [this](https://gist.github.com/manishpatelgt/224a330a5d4c7eaf783ca3ff5d522274)

Comment: older version is also showing previously declared permission

Comment: I am facing the issue, did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

Go to your artifact Library and check if there is any active artifact which contains these permissions. Now create a build and overwrite those active artifacts with your new build. When every other release track like beta , internal do not contain any sensitive permission, just create a build for production and you will see it gone.