# Google Play: The form field "Compliance Status" to delete a previously declared Permission for a new APK is not shown

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions, expo

## Context

I use React Native and Expo to develop an Android application. The problem I have with the Permission Statement is when I publish the APK on Google Play, in the "Publication Management > Application Versions" page.

## Problem

For the previous version of my APK, I had declared READ_SMS permission in Google Play ( "Application Versions" page). **Now, the application no longer needs it; however, Google Play does not offer me a form field to allow me to indicate it to it.** (*cf.* Part "What I have already tried to do > About Google Play")

### Expected results

I would like to be able to delete the declaration of the "READ_SMS" Permission in order to be able to send the new version of the APK. For example thanks to "Compliance Status field" (*cf.* Stackoverflow related questions).

### Current results

Google Play displays me a form where I am required to fill in a type of functionality for the "READ_SMS" Permission (which I no longer need and should therefore be deleted) of the new version of the APK, and I am therefore blocked at this step. Examples of feature types: "Default SMS Manager", "Proxy Calls", "Services - OEM", etc.

Below is a screenshot I did. The types of functionalities are shown, as the (not needed and unwanted) READ_SMS Permission:

The types of functionalities are shown, as the (not needed and unwanted) READ_SMS Permission

[image: The types of functionalities are shown, as the (not needed and unwanted) READ_SMS Permission]

## What I've already tried to do

### At the app.json level

I changed my permissions in app.json, putting only what I need for geolocation:

```
"permissions": [
      "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
      "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
    ],
```

### In Google Play

I followed the following procedure: https://gist.github.com/manishpatelgt/224a330a5d4c7eaf783ca3ff5d522274 (*cf.* Part StackOverflow related questions), which indicates in particular :

1) To "Create a new version";
2) Then click on "Retain the old APK"
3) Here, a form should normally appear with the following field: "No, this release does not meet the SMS and Call Log permissions policy": **I don't see it.** (Compliance Status field, *cf.* Part StackOverflow related questions)

### StackOverflow related questions

1) GitHub procedure provided in commentary: [Previously declared permissions (2 permissions) google play app release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55293576/previously-declared-permissions-2-permissions-google-play-app-release)

2) Compliance Status field found in this question, but I can't see it in my own form: [Permissions Declaration Form still showing in Google Play Console even with updated APK uploaded without READ_CALL_LOG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54689451/permissions-declaration-form-still-showing-in-google-play-console-even-with-upda?rq=1)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried to contact Google Play Store support team?

Comment: No, I'm contacting them now.

Comment: Google Play Store support? No such thing unless you like conversations with bots. Let me know when you figured it out, this is such a pain.

Comment: Thank's.. Yes, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded starting from the internal test version, where I was not asked for permissions sensitive to my application, then I went back to the production version where miraculously the permissions form had disappeared.  I don't know why the google play console absolutely wanted me to select a sensitive permissions, maybe because of the old apk that was in the alpha, beta and test versions and that used sensitive permissions?
The main thing is that now my application only requires geolocation as I wanted and respects Google Play policy.  Have a good day